# Plot very large number of box plots (range between 1 to 10,000) using Tee chart

Tags: boxplot, teechart

I need to allow user to select Start and End data. Once it is selected, i need to fetch all the group data between these dates and display box plot. The problem is box plots are overlaid if there are many box plot needs to be displayed. Tee chart does not automatically shrink the size of boxplot. Also, does not provide scroll to bar to adjust bottom axis to accommodate all the box plots. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code in C# but it did not adjusted the width of box and they were overlapping.

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
            tChart1.Legend.Visible = false;
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            {
                Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Box b = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Box();
                tChart1.Series.Add(b);
                b.Position = i;
                b.FillSampleValues();
            }

            tChart1.Panning.Allow = ScrollModes.Horizontal;
            tChart1.Zoom.Direction = ZoomDirections.Horizontal;

            ReCalculateBoxWidth();

        }
    public void ReCalculateBoxWidth()
    {
        int boxW;
        double tmpW;

        tChart1.Draw();

        tmpW = (tChart1.Chart.ChartRect.Right - tChart1.Chart.ChartRect.Left) / (tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Maximum - tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Minimum) / 2;
        tmpW = tmpW * 0.9;

        boxW = (int)Math.Round(tmpW);

        foreach (Steema.TeeChart.Styles.CustomBox b in tChart1.Series)
        {
            b.Box.SizeUnits = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.PointerSizeUnits.Pixels;
            b.Box.SizeDouble = boxW;
        }

        tChart1.Draw();

    }
```

[image: BoxPlot]

Comment: You should assign the calcualted width to the `b.Box.HorizSize` property instead of `b.Box.SizeDouble`.

Comment: You also missed to assign the Zoom and UnZoom events

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the appropriate box width according to your needs.
Here is is a simple example with 100 boxes that resizes them at Zoom & UnZoom events.

---

### In C# using [TeeChart .NET](https://www.steema.com/product/net)

[image: Box]

Here the code:

```
private void testBoxPlotWidth()
{
  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
  tChart1.Legend.Visible = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    Box b = new Box();
    tChart1.Series.Add(b);
    b.Position = i;
    b.FillSampleValues();
    b.ColorEach = true;
  }

  tChart1.Panning.Allow = ScrollModes.Horizontal;
  tChart1.Zoom.Direction = ZoomDirections.Horizontal;

  ReCalculateBoxWidth();

  tChart1.Zoomed += TChart1_Zoomed;
  tChart1.UndoneZoom += TChart1_UndoneZoom;
}

private void TChart1_UndoneZoom(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ReCalculateBoxWidth();
}

private void TChart1_Zoomed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ReCalculateBoxWidth();
}

public void ReCalculateBoxWidth()
{
  int boxW;
  double tmpW;

  tChart1.Draw();

  tmpW = tChart1.Chart.ChartRect.Width / (tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Maximum - tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Minimum) / 2;
  tmpW = tmpW * 0.7;

  boxW = (int)Math.Round(tmpW);

  foreach (CustomBox b in tChart1.Series)
  {
    b.Box.SizeUnits = PointerSizeUnits.Pixels;
    b.Box.HorizSize = boxW;
  }
}
```

---

### In Delphi using [TeeChart VCL/FMX](https://www.steema.com/product/vcl)

[image: Box]

Here the code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=False;
  Chart1.Legend.Hide;

  for i:=0 to 99 do
    with Chart1.AddSeries(TBoxSeries) as TBoxSeries do
    begin
      Position:=i;
      FillSampleValues;
    end;

  Chart1.AllowPanning:=pmHorizontal;
  Chart1.Zoom.Direction:=tzdHorizontal;

  RecalcBoxWidth;
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1UndoZoom(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RecalcBoxWidth;
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1Zoom(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RecalcBoxWidth;
end;

procedure TForm1.RecalcBoxWidth;
var i, boxW: Integer;
    tmpW: Double;
begin
  Chart1.Draw;

  tmpW:=(Chart1.ChartRect.Right - Chart1.ChartRect.Left) / (Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Maximum - Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Minimum) / 2;
  tmpW:=tmpW*0.9;

  boxW:=Round(tmpW);
  for i:=0 to 99 do
    with Chart1[i] as TBoxSeries do
    begin
      Box.SizeUnits:=suPixels;
      Box.Size:=boxW;
    end;

  Chart1.Draw;
end;
```

Comment: I used your code in c# but box width is not automatically adjusted.

Comment: <pre>tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
    tChart1.Legend.Visible = false;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Box b = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Box();
                tChart1.Series.Add(b);
                b.Position = i;
                b.FillSampleValues();
            }

            tChart1.Panning.Allow = ScrollModes.Horizontal;
            tChart1.Zoom.Direction = ZoomDirections.Horizontal;

            ReCalculateBoxWidth();<code>

Comment: Thank you Yeray. It is working now. I have another problem now. If box plot number is huge (something like 2000) then they are overlapping as teechart's plot area is fixed. Is there any horizontal scroll bar in teechart for X axis  ?

Comment: You can use a regular ScrollBar and adjust the bottom axis scale calling `tChart1.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(min, max);` at the ScrollBar `Change` event.

Comment: If you still find problems with it, create a new question explaining the exact problem and what you've tried so far. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)